# CXF JAXRS - How to POST more than one parameter

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jax-rs

How do I send more than one parameter in request body in a POST request?

```java
@POST
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
@Produces("application/json")
public String addForm1(@FormParam("i1") Integer i1, @FormParam("i2") Integer i2);
```

Above code returns HTTP 415.

Replacing `@FormParam` with `@Multipart` results in `Resource method has more than one parameter representing a request body` error, as shown below.

```
SEVERE: Resource method service.rs.TestService.postData2 has more than one parameter representing a request body
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientWebApplicationException: Resource method service.rs.TestService.postData2 has more than one parameter representing a request body
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.reportInvalidResourceMethod(ClientProxyImpl.java:546)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.getParametersInfo(ClientProxyImpl.java:214)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.invoke(ClientProxyImpl.java:138)
at $Proxy20.postData2(Unknown Source)
at service.TestServiceClient.main(TestServiceClient.java:82)
```

Also, what do I need to do in order to pass multiple complex types such as `List<Map<String, String>>' or 'List<MyNestedCustomObject>` in a POST method? I'm able to pass such parameter by using `JAXB` and annotating it with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`, but I guess that doesn't work in case of passing multiple parameters? Would I be required to define my own message body readers & writers? Any sample code would be useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I figured a way to do this (see code below). But if you know a better way, which preferably does not use the concept of "attachments" and uses jaxrs:client directly instead of  `WebClient`, please let me know.

Service:

```
@POST 
@Path("/postdata3") 
@Consumes("multipart/mixed") 
@Produces("application/json") 
public String postData3(@Multipart(value = "testItem1", type = "application/json") TestItem t1, 
    @Multipart(value = "testItem2", type = "application/json") TestItem t2 
    );
```

Client:

```
    WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://myserver/services/test/postdata3"); 
    client.type("multipart/mixed").accept("application/json"); 
    List<Attachment> atts = new LinkedList<Attachment>(); 
    atts.add(new Attachment("testItem1", "application/json", t1)); 
    atts.add(new Attachment("testItem2", "application/json", t2)); 
    javax.ws.rs.core.Response s = client.postCollection(atts, Attachment.class); 
    System.out.println(s.getStatus());
```

Comment: Can I  use Multipart in config ? In some reason my service interface & implement class  could not use Jax-rs/Cxf annotations,so I want to publish service  in config way.But I found service model  resource schema file jaxrs-common.xsd not support Multipart Param and document did not mentioned that either  on this page http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-multiparts.html , is there any way to use it in config ？ Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `@FormParam` with `@Consumes`; use just `@FormParam` on the parameters and CXF will figure out the rest.

When I pass back results, I return a single JAXB-annotated object that contains the list of things. CXF internally uses [Jettison](http://jettison.codehaus.org/), which uses those JAXB annotations to guide the conversion to JSON. This works pretty well for me.

Comment: Removing `@Consumes` helped. However, I realized I need to pass `@Multipart` params since my params are not simple. I need to POST 2 params of these types: 1. `List<Map<String, String>>` and 2. `MyCustomObject`. Passing 1 such param works fine (I defined `XmlJavaTypeAdapter` for `Map<String, String>` and annotated `MyCustomObject` with `@XmlRootElement`). But when I pass both params, it throws `has more than one parameter representing a request body` error. I tried `multipart/mixed` & `multipart/related` for `@Consumes` and marked params  with `@Multipart`. Appreciate quick help.

Comment: @domino Hmm, you're getting outside the area I know well enough to directly advise. http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-multiparts.html says to use use `@Multipart` _or_ a signature of `List<Attachment>`. What version of CXF are you using?

Comment: Since I am not dealing with any files/attachments as such, I tried out `@Multipart`. Will check if `List<Attachment>` can be of any help. I'm using 2.5.2. There **are** examples on that page which seem to suggest that it should be straight-forward to POST multiple parameters using `@Multipart`. I guess I'm missing something.